# PreventAppSheet (Use only in Mail) - iOS Mail Payload configuration

Tags: iphone, ios, email, mdm, payload

According to iPhone Configuration Profile Reference documentation, you can set `PreventAppSheet` to true when sending an Email Payload. When setting `PreventAppSheet` to `true`, "[the] account is not available for sending mail in
third-party applications".

My question is this, How can I test this feature? I have set up a mail account which uses smtp.gmail.com as an outgoing emaill server and `imap.gmail.com` as an incoming server. I set preventappsheet to true, but I still managed to send emails from third party applications such as Gmail client app, and Mailbox app from iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

PreventAppSheet doesn't mean, that you cannot send mails with this accounts.

It means, that the defined mail account won't be available if you i. e. do "open attachment in mail" from a 3rd party app like a PDF app.